# Compile with Libsodium C

Tags: c, libsodium

I'm trying since 2days to compile a simple code in C with the lib "libsodium"

after doing

```
wget https://download.libsodium.org/libsodium/releases/LATEST.tar.gz > make && make check > make install
```

I want to compile my file.c but i dont know how to call my lib libsodium i tried :

```
gcc file.c -L. -llibsodium

gcc file.c -L. -llibsodium-dev

gcc file.c -L. -llibsodium13

gcc file.c -L. -llibsodium-dbg

gcc file.c -L. -libsodium

gcc file.c -L. -libsodium-dev

gcc file.c -L. -libsodium13

gcc file.c -L. -libsodium-dbg

g++ file.c -L. -llibsodium

g++ file.c -L. -llibsodium-dev

g++ file.c -L. -llibsodium13

g++ file.c -L. -llibsodium-dbg

g++ file.c -L. -libsodium

g++ file.c -L. -libsodium-dev

g++ file.c -L. -libsodium13

g++ file.c -L. -libsodium-dbg
```

but my compilator tell me `"/usr/bin/ld cant' find "thelib"`

Do you guys know about libsodium??

Comment: Where did you install/untar libsodium? What's in your file.c? do you have anything called thelib? cf grep thelib * in your folder

Comment: You have missed the single correct incantation, which is **-lsodium**.

Answer (score 0):

LFAGS in compiling C are usually used as "-llibraryname"
Use `-lsodium` flag to compile it